# Understanding proof of: A submodule of a free module of finite rank is also free of finite rank?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

Sorry in advance for the long exposition; it is necessary to include it.

I am trying to understand the proof of this result from Dummit & Foote (so in particular, I can't use the result yet):

> Let $R$ be a Principal Ideal Domain, let $M$ be a free $R$ - module of finite rank $n$ and let $N$ be a submodule of $M$. Then
>
> $(1)$ $N$ is free of rank $m$, $m \le n$ and
>
> $(2)$ there exists a basis $y_1, y_2, ..., y_n$ of $M$ so that $a_1y_1, a_2y_2, ..., a_my_m$ is a basis of $N$ where $a_1, a_2, ..., a_m$ are nonzero elements of $R$ with the divisibility relations
>
> $$a_1|a_2| \cdots | a_m$$

Somewhere in the middle of the proof, it says:

> We now verify that this element $y_1$ can be taken as one element in a basis for $M$ and that $a_1y_1$ can be taken as one element in a basis for $N$, namely that we have
>
> $(a)$ $M=Ry_1 \oplus \ker v$, and
>
> $(b)$ $N = Ra_1y_1 \oplus (N \cap \ker v)$

This is the part I have a question about. It seems like there is a hidden theorem here which says

> ($\pm$ some assumptions of $R$ being an integral domain or a P.I.D.)
>
> If $M$ is a free $R$-module, $N$ is a submodule, and $M = Ry \oplus N$, then there exists a basis of $M$ containing $y$.

However, I do not know how to prove this. If we already assumed the result, it would not be difficult; just take any basis for $N$ and adjoin it to $y$. However, without the result I am stuck.

**Question:** Did I identify the hidden theorem correctly? If so, how do we prove it?

Comment: We can take any element of M and construct a basis. As an example, think of a vector space V. To construct a basis for V. One can start with any non-zero vector v$_1$ and then take another vector v$_2$ $\not\in$ Span(v$_1$). Then take v$_3$ $\not\in$ Span(v$_1$,v$_2$). Continue this process. A similar thing happens with free modules in general.

Comment: @JoelPereira I understand why for later they might want to show that $M=Ry_1 \oplus \ker v$, but why mention explicitly that "we will show that $y_1$ can be taken as a basis for M"? Do you think they are just being redundant?

Comment: It's not true in general that $any$ y can be be used as part of the basis for BOTH M and N. It's true for M always, but not necessarily the case for a general submodule.

Comment: @JoelPereira But as long as that $y$ is an element of both the module and the submodule, then it can be used for a basis, right?

Comment: Yes. But the proof is also saying that the a$_i$ have that divisibility condition.